# How to find the duplicate values and sort via column?

Tags: database, excel

I am trying to do the following:

i have a sorted column (A) and unsorted columns (C,D,E,F,G,H,I) that all together contains person descriptions such as email e.t.c. The A column has the same type of data with the column C.
How can i find the duplicates between A and C and then, sort the CDEFGHI based on A ? So the Column C will have only the same data from A ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column (say, column `D`) with formula like

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($C2,$A:$A,1,0)),0,1)
```

So 1 means duplicate value and 0 means unique value (exists in columm `C` but not in `A`).